# Icon 16x16 best way

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, icon, pixelation

Anyone know a good tutorial for learning to do 16x16 icon?

The PROBLEM is when I'm doing in photoshop or illustrator and export the image in that size have like a transition effect.

Example : black-> grey pixel -> white

Not sure if I should do pixel art...The only thing I want is create a black and white icon, no transition color.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you saying that you want ONLY black and white pixels? And no gray pixels at all? If so, convert to BITMAP in photoshop and then tweak as necessary. Note that for a 16px icon to look smooth, you likely WILL Need various gray pixels in there to antialias things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to start with a 16x16 file and hand tweak each pixel.

Comment: Uhm..but is hard, most of them look awful doing that, not seem the same, any tutorials to check?

Thanks

Comment: It's an issue of drawing/illustration skills. If you are having a specific issue with a specific icon, post that and we can offer some suggestions hopefully.

Comment: +1. The smaller you go, the more the individual pixels count. At some point you have to edit individual pixels.